# Graphics - refreshing just one object

Tags: graphics, grid, drawing, refresh, panel

With my friend we are trying to make some game. When we draw a grid or checkerboard and then move objects by arrows, "panel.Refresh();" refresh all the objects, obviously the complete panel. Can we somehow refresh just that objects, which are supposed to move? We tried to make two panels. First panel generates the grid and the second one generates the object which is supposed to move, but when the object moves, the panel with the grid blink whenever the panel with object takes refresh. Can someone help us please? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to add some code so anyone can help you. By just your text we can hardly get a glimpse of what you want and mean. Try to create a small compiled program that works like the problem you are posting here with only what is strictly needed to reproduce your problem and post the source code here.